# Please include the ability to cross-reference existing Docs within Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

We've already started [coming across some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/flask/1789/working-with-json#t=201607221928046386488) of duplicate information being presented a number of times. In this example, the Flask framework uses generic JSON requests, and so there are some examples with generic JSON requests.

The suggestion I made to the user asking about it was to include a topic or example called "JSON Requests in Flask" or something similar, and simply link to the JSON tag's topics/examples themselves, considering they are generic.

That's when it hit me. Obviously a link-only example is not much good, but this is bound to be a hugely popular issue at least with web-based technologies like JSON where many frameworks and languages use the exact same implementations.

It would be absolutely wonderful if we had the ability to "embed" (*a la* oneboxing) an extant Documentation example in the topic of another tag. So that way any time someone votes on the JSON example embedded in the Flask topic for JSON, they're really voting on the JSON example from the JSON topic.

This way, we avoid duplication, people don't have to get confused about "well what topicality rules apply here? Do I duplicate the content since it's a very common thing to need to know for this framework/library?", *and* the contributors of the original topic will get credit for votes that are sent from external pages.

Heck, you could even add some badges for it.

Comment: Should this be a topic embeded in the tag, or an example embeded in a topic?  I was thinking more the later, where an example from another tag/topic would be rendered inline and votable in another topic.

Comment: @davidism I agree. I've adjusted the verbiage to be more clear/open about it, too.

Comment: excel-vba already has a few topics that should be available from vba, word-vba, and access-vba.

Comment: As fo right now the best you can do is click the "share" button for an entry and use the link to refer to it from other documentation pages.