# "Duplicate" or "copied" examples in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

Some examples are in different topics, but they're exactly the same. For example, if there's a topic on *scoping* and a topic on *functions,* both would have a *function scope* example.

When adding a new example to a Documentation topic, I think the ability to mark an example as an exact duplicate of another example would be useful. Currently, if one wants to add an example that happens to be the exact same as another example in a different topic, they'd have to rewrite it or it'd be plagiarism if they copy-and-paste it.

People may also not know that both examples exist, so the more popular one could be edited much more frequently, resulting in one example being more descriptive than the other. A duplicate notice would alert users that the exact/very similar example exists somewhere else.

A "duplicate example" or "copy example" feature would make this sort of thing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two topic have an example that fits to both of them this probably means that they need to be merged. If not i'll go for the cross-reference as in the following post : 
[Please include the ability to cross-reference existing Docs within Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329049/please-include-the-ability-to-cross-reference-existing-docs-within-documentation?rq=1)